# Display field based on another in JointJS

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I have an inspector which contains a list of object has name and type, and my custom data. Let say i wanna display my custom data base on the choice of type attribute. I can do this with 'when' but it's only if it is the simple field with specific path like "attr/type". Since it's in the list, the index vary so i dont know how to specify the path to check whether what type is chosen. Any idea for this problem ?

```
    data: {
                        type : 'list',
                        item: {
                            type: 'object',
                            properties: {
                                'name' : {
                                    type : 'text',
                                    group : 'text',
                                    label : 'Name',
                                    index : 1
                                },
                                type : {
                                    type : 'select',
                                    group : 'text',
                                            label : 'Type',
                                            options: ['Text','Number','Date','Select','Text Area'],
                                    index : 2
                                },
                                required : {
                                    type : 'toggle',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    label : 'Required',
                                    index : 3
                                },
                                'min-length' : {
                                    type : 'number',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    min : 0,
                                    label : 'Min Length',
                                    index : 4
                                },
                                'max-length' : {
                                    type : 'number',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    min : 1,
                                    label : 'Max Length',
                                    index : 5
                                },
                                'min' : {
                                    type : 'number',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    min : 0,
                                    label : 'Min',
                                    index : 6
                                },
                                'max' : {
                                    type : 'number',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    min : 1,
                                    label : 'Max',
                                    index : 7
                                },
                                'message' : {
                                    type : 'text',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    label : 'Error message',
                                    index : 8
                                },
                                'regex' : {
                                    type : 'text',
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    label : 'Regex',
                                    index : 9
                                },
                                'options' : {
                                    type : 'list',
                                    item : {
                                        type:'object',
                                        properties: {
                                            'text' : {
                                                type : 'text',
                                                label : 'Text',
                                                index : 1
                                            },
                                            'value' :{
                                                type : 'text',
                                                label : 'Value',
                                                index : 2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    group : 'validation',
                                    label : 'Options',
                                    index : 10
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        group : 'validation',
                        label : 'Input',
                        index : 1
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I affraid you need to create a field for each type from the name/type collection. Similar problem is solved here:

```
operator: {
                type: 'select',
                options: ['over', 'in', 'out', 'atop', 'xor', 'arithmetic'],
            },
            k1: {
                type: 'number',
                when: { eq: { operator: 'or' } }
            },
            k2: {
                type: 'number',
                when: { eq: { operator: 'arithmetic' } }
            },
            k3: {
                type: 'number',
                when: { eq: { operator: 'xor' } }
            },
            k4: {
                type: 'number',
                when: { eq: { operator: 'over' } }
            }
```

**EDIT**:

it's obvious this approach cannot be used in your case... xpath 
`when: { eq: { 'labels/0/type': 'Number' } }` is valid but useless. It's not doable easilly so far, we set up a new issue for this. Would be nice to have something like `when: { eq: { '*/type': 'Number' } }` where `*` could be current context, so you would be able to get current index.

Comment: Could u be more detail ? I edited my post to provide more information. As u can see, i want to set my 'regex' field appear only when my 'type' is 'Date' or 'Number'. Thank you

Comment: any suggest solution sir ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide inside the Attribute of particular element..

For example you need to hide the message element based on attr/type option You need to write the code like that..

```
                        'message' : {
                                type : 'text',
                                group : 'validation',
                                label : 'Error message',
                                when: { ne: { 'data/item/type': "Your Option here!!"} },
                                index : 8
                            },
```

Suggestions are welcome!! Thank you

Comment: Why are you down voting.. is there any suggestion means comment